Session is Null in .net standard class library when passed from .NET 8 WebApp
I have .NET 8 WebApp, and .NET Standard 2.0 class library.
I am using System.WebAdapters 1.4 so that I can do incremental migration from ASP.NET 4.8 WebApp to .NET 8 WebApp.
My .NET 8 WebApp Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddSystemWebAdapters()
    .AddJsonSessionSerializer(options =>
    {
        // Serialization/deserialization requires each session key to be registered to a type
        options.RegisterKey<int>("IncidentID");
    });

builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});

// If using IIS:
builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});

// Add configuration services to access settings
var configuration = builder.Configuration;


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseSystemWebAdapters();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages().RequireSystemWebAdapterSession();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "ashxRoute",
                    pattern: "uicomponents/handlers/{*path}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "LegacyHandler", action = "ProcessRequest" }).RequireSystemWebAdapterSession();
});

app.Run();

My Controller File,
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using company.SharedHandlers.Handlers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters;

namespace SampleWebApp
{
    public class NoiseWordsController : Controller
    {
        //private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        //public NoiseWordsController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ISessionManager)
        //{
        //    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        //}
        [Session]
        [Route("uicomponents/handlers/NoiseWords.ashx")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            NoiseWords noiseWords = new NoiseWords();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["IncidentID"] = "200";
            noiseWords.ProcessRequest(HttpContext);
            return View();

        }
    }
}

After running the project, I get
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters.ISessionManager' has been registered.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<T>(IServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters.SessionLoadMiddleware.ManageStateAsync(HttpContext context, ISessionStateFeature feature)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters.PreBufferRequestStreamMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

When I remove Session attribute from controller, and also remove RequireSystemWebAdapterSession(). Then I get NULL Session at System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["IncidentID"] = "200";
My goal is to pass this session to my class library.
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace company.SharedHandlers.Handlers
{
    public class NoiseWords : BaseHandler
    {
        public string cleanString = null;

        protected override void DoProcess(HttpContext context)
        {
            // list of potential operations.
            switch (RequestParam("sp"))
            {
                case "NoiseWords":
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                    context.Response.Headers["CacheControl"] = "no-cache";
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                    context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "-1";
                    context.Response.Write("NoiseWords operation");

                    break;
             
            }
        }
    }
}


Here, in the above method I should be able to access the Session info (IncidentID).
What should I do?

I suggest you could follow this article and try this :builder.Services.AddSystemWebAdapters()     .AddJsonSessionSerializer(options =>     {         // Serialization/deserialization requires each session key to be registered to a type         options.RegisterKey<int>("test-value");         options.RegisterKey<SessionDemoModel>("SampleSessionItem");     })     .WrapAspNetCoreSession();

Create an interface for example ISessionStore.  Put it in a common place so that any project can have access to it.
Implement it in the net core project like so:
public class SessionStore:ISessionStore
{
 private readonly HttpContextAccessor _context;
 public SessionStore(HttpContextAccessor context)
 {
   _context = context
 }
  //Implement methods for getting and setting session data
}

Then register with the net core DI and pass the interface between net standard and netcore libraries.
Hope this helps.

How do we pass this interface from the .net core controller to the .net standard? I need my .net standard class to be compatible with .net framework 4.8 as well.

You will have the interface in a library that both projects can see.  In your statup/program you will use DI like services.AddScoped<ISessionStore,SessionStore>();.
